# How to group Commands?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I want to group Commands in two groups : one in the left and one in the right. For example Commands "Main menu" , "Clients", "Credits" and "Exit" are grouped at the left , and Commands "Detail client", "Detail credit" are grouped at the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047751/left-and-right-command-menus-in-lwuit-form) existing discussion. It will helps you.